# Strange error for copying data

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, copy

I am trying to read video frames in OpenCV, then copy the data into my another C++ code to perform something else. My code is as follows:

```
cv::Mat capturedFrame; 
int newData[600][800];
std::cout<<"Debug1 " << std::endl;
memcpy((char*)newData, (char*)capturedFrame.data, 600*800*sizeof(int) );
std::cout<<"Debug2 " << std::endl;
mycode.setData ( newData );
std::cout<<"Debug3 " << std::endl;
```

Then the class "setData" was defined as follows:

```
char data [600][800];
void mycode::setData ( char newData[600][800] )
{
  for ( int m=0; m < 600; m ++ )
  {
      for ( int n = 0; n < 800; n ++ )
      {
          data[i][j] = newData[i][j]; 
      }
  }
}
```

But the code stops when it comes to the line:

```
    mycode.setData ( newData );
```

What confuses me is, if I delete this code, then I can see "Debug1" to "Debug3" on the screen, which is normal. But if I use this code, the program stops even without printing out "Debug1" and "Debug2" on the screen. This is really strange. I also tried to comment out all the lines in the "setData" class to make it be an empty class, but the error still is the same. So I believe it was not about the "setData" class. 
I also know that the "capturedFrame.data" was correct, because I performed some other filters on it, and the result was good. Can someone explain the error here?

Edit:

I used a debugger, but there was no error message but the program just stopped responding.  Also, I changed the data type into "char".

Comment: Can you cut-n-paste your code?  The line `data = newData;` should not even compile, much less get you to a runtime problem.

Comment: You're assigning the same value 480000 times in the line `data = newData` in `mycode::setData` function. If both buffers are from the same size you can use `memcpy`. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810668) to know more about arrays in c++.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I edited into "data[i][j]=[i][j]".

Comment: To start with, have you tried running your program in a debugger? Also, shouldn't it be `data[m][n] = newData[m][n];` in your loop? And don't you think using something like [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or even [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) would be more effective?

Comment: yes, I tried running in a debugger, but there was no error message, but the program just stops responding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This array:

```
int newData[600][800];
```

is larger than 1 MB.  If this is a local variable, then you're likely blowing the stack.

The same may go for the `data` array, but since your code snippets have very little context, it's hard to know what might be statically allocated vs. automatically allocated.

I think you should consider dynamically allocating these large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out

```
mycode.setData ( newData );
```

the compile-optimizer may know the `newData` is not used, so

```
memcpy((int*)newData, (int*)capturedFrame.data, 600*800*sizeof(int) );
```

may be eliminated as well so it may not have been executed.

It's possible the problem exist in `memcpy` method, or even somewhere else.

Based on the limited information you provided, it's hard to investigate the real reason, but I suggest you can look deeper into other code.